# Using cPanel's EMAIL authentication to facilitate access into custom built CMS

Tags: php, cpanel

I was building custom CMS using adminLTE theme.

I have users with email accounts and passwords created inside from cPanel on the same host.

Regarding to login part for the users, i was wondering if i could authenticate users using their own email address and password i.e. i want to allow users to log in to my build CMS hosted on their hosting account using their own email account login details.

Do anybody have any idea how can i use cPanel API or something, to get access token or authentication status once the request is made with email address and password.

I am using hostgator as hosting provider, using PHP 7.1,  cPanel version 78.0.38